# VB.NET: Sum of Checked Boxes, Radio buttons and TextBoxes

Tags: vb.net

I am making a simple car shop accounting software which has a panel of `3 checkboxes` for **additional accessories** of the car and a `group box of 3 radiobutton` controls for **car-detailing**. I have a `base price textbox` and `calculate button`.

I have a sheet of pre-defined costs of **additional accessories** of the car and

> - Stereo system=         *$40,000*
>
>   - Leather interior   =       *$150,000*
>   - Computer navigation=   *$100,000*
>   - Standard             =*No additional charge*
>   - Pearlized=      *$30,000*
>   - Customized detailing   =     *$50,000*

I just used a simple method of Sum but I get an error :

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred
>   in Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
>
> Additional information: Conversion from string "" to type 'Double' is
>   not valid.

Here is the code that am running with:

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
        Dim Sum As Integer
        ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Stereo system + Base Price
        If Rad1.Checked + Chk1.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "40,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Stereo system + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "40,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Stereo system + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad3.Checked + Chk1.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "40,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad3.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "150,00"
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Computer Navigation+ Base Price
        ElseIf Rad3.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum



            ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "40,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Computer Navigation+  Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "40,000" + "150,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Stereo system + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "40,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Standard Detailing +  Leather Interior  + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "100,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum


            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "40,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Computer Navigation+  Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "40,000" + "150,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing + Stereo system + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "40,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Pearlized Detailing +  Leather Interior  + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "30,000" + "100,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum



            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "40,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Stereo system +  Leather Interior + Computer Navigation+  Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "40,000" + "150,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing + Stereo system + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk1.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "40,000" + "100,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum
            ' Sum of Customised Detailing +  Leather Interior  + Computer Navigation + Base Price
        ElseIf Rad2.Checked + Chk2.Checked + Chk3.Checked + basePrice.Text Then
            Sum = "50,000" + "100,000" + "150,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
            subTotal.Text = Sum

        End If
```

The rule is a customer can buy any car with any or ALL accessories but he/she must choose ONLY one(1) type/form of car detailing.

Where am I going wrong. Please help thank you.

Comment: Change In the project settings `Option Strict` to `On`. Or write in the first line of your code file `Option Strict On` and you will get answer

Comment: A quick stepping through the code, while debugging should reveal the errors

Comment: @Fabio `Option Strict = On` worked but with all the repetition in my work ..there was so much to be done. I got over 30 errors with that but with effort it was working. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. Just a few problems :)

All your numbers "30,000" "40,000" etc are strings for a start.

Using Val produced a double type as a result and if your textbox is empty then you will get the error in your post. If there is no value to enter for a trade-in still enter a 0

Also your If statements are using "**+**" instead of **And** which will produce logic errors.

Also when dealing with money, you should never use Integers

And you should never write code with Option Strict set to Off in your default compiler settings. It's a bit more difficult writing code with Option Strict set to On, but it reduces the possibility of errors when the program is run

Instead of code like this :-

```
If Rad1.Checked + Chk1.Checked + basePrice.Text>"" Then
    Sum = "40,000" + Val(tradeIn.Text) + Val(basePrice.Text)
    subTotal.Text = Sum
```

You should be using this

```
    Dim Sum As Single
    ' Sum of Standard Detailing + Stereo system + Base Price
    If Rad1.Checked And chk1.Checked And BasePrice.Text > "" Then
        Sum = 40000 + CSng(TradeIn.Text) + CSng(BasePrice.Text)
        subTotal.Text = Sum.ToString
```

But to be honest (no offence), there is a lot of repetition and there are probably lots of ways of shortening it - my suggestion for this would be

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Calculate.Click
    Dim Sum As Single
    Dim Base As Single = CSng(BasePrice.Text)
    Dim Trade As Single = CSng(TradeIn.Text)
    Dim Stereo As Single = 0
    Dim LeatherInt As Single = 0
    Dim CompNav As Single = 0
    Dim Pearlized As Single = 0
    Dim CustomDetail As Single = 0

    If chk1.Checked Then Stereo = 40000
    If chk2.Checked Then LeatherInt = 150000
    If chk3.Checked Then CompNav = 100000
    If Rad2.Checked Then Pearlized = 30000
    If Rad3.Checked Then CustomDetail = 50000
    Sum = Base + Trade + Stereo + LeatherInt + CompNav + Pearlized + CustomDetail
    subTotal.Text = Sum.ToString()
End Sub
```

And dont forget to add checks into your code to make sure that the numbers for the base price and trade-in price are actually numbers. When you enter the numbers in the textboxes, dont use commas like this **50,000**, just enter **50000**

Comment: Yes I just noticed that when i was offline. Thank you it worked!